# What method is appropriate for the following differential equation?

Tags: differential

[Differential Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yZuY.jpg)

I am stuck at this equation what method is appropriate and how I should solve it?

> $$\left(x e^y-1\right)dy= -\left(e^{x+y}+e^y y\right)dx$$

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yZuY.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If there is a solution, I bet that it would involve Lambert function.

Comment: There is a solution and it involves Lambert function. ! We are still waiting to know what you already tried.